# Why the double quotes are not displaying correctly?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, amsmath, miktex, unicode

Double quotes in the following example are not displaying correctly. What I may be missing here and how can I make it look like "example"?

**Environment**: `MikTeX` on `Windows 10`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\section*{Examples }

Following is an "example"  for test:

\[\frac{a}{c}\]

\end{document}
```

**PDF file screenshot of the above tex file**:

[image]

**UPDATE**:

Comments from users `@Schrödinger's cat` and `@egreg` yields the following. This probably seems to be the correct way of doing it in `LaTeX`. I was hoping for `"example"` that does not seem to be the correct way in `tex`:

**From LaTex file**:

```
Following is an ``example'' for test:

Another test “example”
```

**PDF output**:

[image]

Comment: Use `Following is an ``example''  for test:`.

Comment: Every LaTeX tutorial explains that `"` should not be used for quotes. Either use `` \`\` `` and `''` or `“` and `”`

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Your suggestion did not help.

Comment: Well, did you try it out?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I guess he did not. :)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I've added an **UPDATE** section based on your comments. Your suggestion seem to be the way to go in `LaTeX`.

Comment: @egreg I've added an **UPDATE** section after I tried your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: I's suggest having a look at the `csquotes` package as for some ``back tick/ping:  ` `` is very hard to type in their keyboard. With `csquotes` one can use `\enquote{word}` and then control from the preamble which quotes should be added.

Comment: @daleif Yes, typing some characters from my Microsoft keyboard is an issue. For example, I cannot find `“` on my keyboard. I would look into the `csquotes` package as an alternative, as well.

Comment: There is no such thing as `“` on any keyboard. It is a unicode char. Traditional by hand method is two backpings on the left and two apostrophs on the right (ascii chars that is). I cannot tell you where those chars are as I don't know your keyboard layout. For example I use a standard Microsoft US keyboard (as it is better to programon than than the normal for my language). On this keyboard layout the backping sits right above the Tab key, and apostrophe just left of Enter.

Comment: @daleif Most keyboard *layouts* presumably support this no? Certainly on the Mac, they are supported out of the box. `“` is Opt-[ and `”` is Opt-Shift-[ and similarly for their single quote versions (Opt-] and Opt-Shift-] respectively).

Comment: @AlanMunn of course you can insert it if you know the right combination. Though Macs are particularly bad here as they does not even show where most of the normal chars are. On a Danish Mac keyboard it is not shown where `[]`, `{}` or ``\`` are. At least they are shown on a normal Dansih non-Mac keyboard.

Comment: @daleif Yes. My comment was a bit too English centred indeed.

Comment: @AlanMunn this is the basic DK Mac layout: https://66.media.tumblr.com/68ff312f066f5b924e613d3421744adb/71914e168d298b8c-9e/s500x750/bbe05be41a8f92321fb329ea51b99c1071e89984.jpg